# Reactjs - Why can't i set state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

Hi i'm trying to fetch a user data from jsonplaceholder and update my state with that data. I had no problem fetching the data and logging it to the console. But when i try to setState, i still get an empty object. 
I appreciate any help. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    profileDetails: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDetails();
  }

  fetchDetails = async () => {
    const baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
    const pathname = this.props.history.location.pathname;
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}${pathname}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);                 // I can see the data i want here in the console.

    this.setState = { profileDetails: data };
    console.log(this.state.profileDetails);       // I get an empty object here.
  };

  render() {
    return <h1>Name: {this.state.profileDetails.name}</h1>;
  }
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

**Thanks everyone for taking the time to answer. Apparently i used setState wrong and missed the fact that it's asynchronous.**

Comment: Look at the way setState is used  https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: try new way of hooks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From docs of [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied
> immediately.

If you want to use up-to-date data, use *callback* argument (and use it as function, instead of assignment, because it is a method, not a property)

```
this.setState({ profileDetails: data }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.profileDetails)
})
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
this.setState = { profileDetails: data };
console.log(this.state.profileDetails);
```

into this

```
this.setState({ profileDetails: data });
```

Put `console.log(this.state.profileDetails);` inside render for you to see your new state.

setState is a function that recieves data as parameters.
but you use it like setState is a json object

Comment: Your welcome.
also, if you console log the state,

do it on render. for you to see the new updated state

Answer (score 2):

setState - is a method.
Please change code like this - this.setState({ profileDetails: data });

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried. Still not updating the state.

Comment: setState is asynchronous

Comment: setState does not immediately changes the state. Once by default due to setState re-rendered takes place, then will be able to see the changes you have made to the state object.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to set state is this,

```
this.setState({ profileDetails: data  })
```

You have to set state by this way only.

Answer (score 0):

Give a condition for check the data is available or not:-

```
if(data)
this.setState = ({ profileDetails: data });
```